# ValueError: External ID not found in the system: module_name.crm_lead_mail_template

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-12

I am a starter in odoo. Can anyone help me to find a solution for the problem mentioned below?

hi all i have created a email template to trigger mail notification when this field changes so i have created this function but iam unable to process this iam getting error when i select mark as won or any field

```
    lead_status = fields.Many2one("crm.stage","Lead Status",track_visibility='onchange',default=_get_default_lead_status)

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        if 'lead_status' in vals and self.ids:
            for rec in self:
                template_id =self.env.ref('crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template').id
                #template = self.env.ref('crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template')
                #template = self.env.ref('module_name.crm_lead_mail_template')
                template.send_mail(rec.id, force_send=True)          
        return super(crm_extended, self).write(vals)


mail template :
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<odoo>

    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="crm_lead_mail_template" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">CRM-OPPORTUNITY_MODIFIED: Send by email</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="crm_extended.model_crm_lead_extended"/>
            <field name="email_from">guna19may2015@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="email_to">${object.account_manager.email}</field>
            <field name="subject">Opportunity Record Has Been modified</field>
            <field name="body_html" type="html">
                <div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                    <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px;">
                        Dear ${object.account_manager.display_name} 
                        <br /><br />
                        Opportunity ${object.customer_name.display_name}  has been Modified. . 

                        <br /><br />
                        Thank you


                    </p>
                </div>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>


when i change select mark as won or any state it shows me below error 

error :
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 88, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData.xmlid_lookup at 0x7f99c64197b8>, 'crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 98, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/crm_internal_new/crm_extended/models/crm_lead_extended.py", line 122, in action_convert_nurture
    self.write({'lead_status': self.nurture_id})
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/crm_internal_new/crm_extended/models/crm_lead_extended.py", line 88, in write
    template_id =self.env.ref('crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template').id
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/api.py", line 864, in ref
    return self['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_object(xml_id, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1443, in xmlid_to_object
    t = self.xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(xmlid, raise_if_not_found)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1427, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
  File "<decorator-gen-25>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 93, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1416, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template



    SOMEONE HELP ME WITH THIS I HAVE TRIED DIFFERENT FUNCTIONS AS BELOW BUT STILL GETTING THE SAME ERROR:

#@api.multi
#def write(self, vals):
    #if 'lead_status' in vals and self.ids:
        #for rec in self:
            #template=self.env.ref('crm_lead_extended.crm_lead_mail_template')
            #template = self.env.ref('mail_template_demo.example_email_template')
            #template = self.env.ref('crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template')
            #template = self.env.ref('module_name.crm_lead_mail_template')
            #template.send_mail(rec.id, force_send=True)          
    #return super(crm_extended, self).write(vals)

@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    res = super(crm_extended, self).write(vals)
    if vals.get('lead_status'):
        template_id = self.env.ref('crm_lead_extended.crm_lead_mail_template')
        for lead in self:
            template_id.send_mail(lead.id)
    return res
#@api.multi
#def submit_expenses(self):
    #self.write({'state': 'mgr_approval'})
    #template = self.env.ref('reimbursement.reim_mgr_approve_email_templates')
    #self.env['mail.template'].browse(template.id).send_mail(self.id)
#def crm_send_mail(self):
    #print("send_mail when lead_status changes")
    #template_id =self.env.ref('crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template').id
    #self.env['mail.template'].browse(template_id).send_mail(self.id,force_send=True)
```

Comment: `'crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template'` is wrong value in your custom module self.env.ref .

Comment: should be `module_name.view_id`

Comment: sorry i didn't get it , can u please elaborate it bro

Comment: template =self.env.ref('crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template') like this ?

Comment: ` File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/crm_internal_new/crm_extended/models/crm_lead_extended.py", line 88, in write
    template_id =self.env.ref('crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template').id` this line told you that the value is wrong, system can not find exact view

Comment: if your IDE is pyCharm. Please search(ctrl+shfit+f) `self.env.ref` in odoo source code to see correct way.

Comment: i have changed it , but still getting the same error  Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 88, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData.xmlid_lookup at 0x7fab128640d0>, 'crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template')

Comment: `template_id =self.env.ref('crm_lead_extended.crm_lead_mail_template').id`

Comment: this is my function now : 
 @api.multi
 def write(self, vals):
        res = super(crm_extended, self).write(vals)
        if vals.get('lead_status'):
            template_id = self.env.ref('crm_lead_extended.crm_lead_mail_template').id
            for lead in self:
                template_id.send_mail(lead.id)
        return res , still getting the same error bro

Comment: If it still shows External ID error. It means that is not the correct value.

Comment: Where you define the `crm_lead_mail_template` xml doc? Check both the module_name and the view_id value.

Comment: i have defined inside views and added in manifest too , check the post again i have edited and added it for you , idk this error is getting into my head iam stucked here for a while

Comment: my module folder name is crm_extended                                                                   in .py file - class crm_extended(models.Model):
    _name = 'crm.lead.extended'
    _rec_name = 'customer_name'
    _inherit = ['portal.mixin', 'mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']                                      in xml file :         <record id="crm_lead_mail_template" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">CRM-OPPORTUNITY_MODIFIED: Send by email</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="crm_extended.model_crm_lead_extended"/>

Comment: my current function : @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        if 'lead_status' in vals and self.ids:
            for rec in self:
                template = self.env.ref('crm.lead.extended.crm_lead_mail_template').id
                template.send_mail(rec.id, force_send=True)          
        return super(crm_extended, self).write(vals)

Comment: what is the directory_name of your custom module? If you check the odoo source code, there is a module manifest named `Employee Contracts` but it's dirctory name is `hr_contract`. When other modules inherit its template, it used `hr_contract.view_id` not `Employee Contracts.view_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external id used in the `send_mail` method is wrong, you must use `module_name.template_id`.

As I can see in the log error your module name is `crm_extended` and the template id is `crm_lead_mail_template`, so you must refer to the template with the following external id:

```
crm_extended.crm_lead_mail_template
```